# VBA Select Case Runtime Error 13

Tags: vba, excel, select, case

I am trying to run a select case for when a cell is changed in a range to run a macro when specific text is entered. I have this working for a single cell (and the code that follows) for "F50", but when I try to use the same style of code a few lines later, it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F50")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Range("F50")
    Case "MPR-9A": Resize9
    Case "MPR-8A": Resize8
    Case "MPR-6A": Resize6
    Case "MPR-3A": Resize3
End Select
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F45")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Range("F4:F45")
    Case "M-20A": M20A
    Case "M-2X20A": M2X20A
    Case "M-20A-SP": M20ASP
End Select
End If

End Sub
```

I am trying to have this code run when I put a new value somewhere in the range of F4:F45. When that value is entered, the case checks for which macro to run.
The macros copy a range on another sheet and paste it to the cell that just triggered the macro (which also includes a few cells to the right and below), and those macros run fine when I fire them manually.

I went the copy/paste route because I gave up on plan A, which was trying to merge the cell that just received the new value with 1 or 3 below it and then enter text into the cells just to the right. If I should return to trying that route I'm more than happy to try and avoid the copy and paste.

Comment: `Range("F4:F45")` is the case for testing, but that doesn't return a string - which is what you're trying to test it against. If you added `Case Else: Debug.Assert False` in that block the code will halt and you'll see.

Comment: That's because you need to disable events and add a `DoEvents` in there somewhere - I'm assuming the subs you are calling change the sheet at some point and so the code calls itself - resulting in an infinite loop, which will crash Excel. A common pitfall of using event triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried Macro Man's solution, but it crashed Excel. I also tried R3UK's solution, but it returned a runtime error. I edited the OP to clarify what is happening with the macros

Comment: @N.Volchko : What **error number** and on **which line** plz? Btw, reply on the specific answer (or use `@` like in this comment to send a notif to one user per comment maximum)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Range("F4:F45").Cells(1,1)` which will in facts be `F4` cell.

But I guess that the **thing you want to test is** `Target.Value`, the value of the cell that changed :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F50")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Range("F50")
    Case "MPR-9A": Resize9
    Case "MPR-8A": Resize8
    Case "MPR-6A": Resize6
    Case "MPR-3A": Resize3
End Select
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F45")) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.value
    Case "M-20A": M20A
    Case "M-2X20A": M2X20A
    Case "M-20A-SP": M20ASP
End Select
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Target` or `Cells(1, 1)` is only going to return the value of a _single_ cell - but the OP wants to test against a _range_ of cells so this would't work. The options are either to create a string from the cells being tested or loop through each of the cells in that range and test individually.

Comment: @MacroMan : Yup, I commented you answer too! Waiting for OP clarification!

Comment: @MacroMan : Apparently, my solution did the trick and the OP disappeared!^^

Comment: @R3uK, I had to add 'If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub' before the select case because the target could occasionally be a merged cell.

Comment: Nicely spotted, I indeed use this too but totally forgot to put it in your answer! My bad! ;) and BTW, it is `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub`

Answer (score 2):

Use this for your second block instead if you just want to check the existence of those strings:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F45")) Is Nothing Then
tempStr = Join([TRANSPOSE[F4:F45)]," ")
    Select Case True
        Case InStr("M-20A", tempStr): M20A
        Case InStr("M-2X20A", tempStr): M2X20A
        Case InStr("M-20A-SP", tempStr): M20ASP
    End Select
End If
```

---

If you want to check each cell individually, then you will have to loop through that range:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F45")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Range("F4:F45").Cells
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "M-20A": M20A
            Case "M-2X20A": M2X20A
            Case "M-20A-SP": M20ASP
        End Select
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Waiting for OP clarification, but this may generate multiple cases regarding the previous values in the range. But nice use of the `Select` with `Instr`, I never saw that, but will probably use it some day! Thx for this!

Comment: I've basically flipped the logic of `Select Case` - you can have the test case as `True` and then just create any expression you like to test - sometimes is much simpler than using an `If/ElseIf` block and _always_ faster.